# Add-on or "trick" to scroll directly to bottom of a auto-loading page

Tags: javascript, java, browser

I would like to know, if there is a possibility for a user to instead of scrolling all the time there is a possibility to load directly the whole page (not an "auto-scrolling add-on).

Comment: This is a bad performance practice for the client, thats why you should use lazy loading

Comment: I am the client and want to reach directly the bottom ;)

Comment: when i say client, i mean the browser xD

Answer (score 0):

I found this function here: [...infinite auto-scroll to bottom of page](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=758)

```
function scrollToBottom(){
  bottom = document.body.scrollHeight;
  current = window.innerHeight+ document.body.scrollTop;
  if((bottom-current) >0){
    window.scrollTo(0, bottom);
    setTimeout ( 'scrollToBottom()', 1000 );
  }
};
scrollToBottom();
```

I ran it in my console and it appears to work. It looks like it could use a little work as the timer may never stop. Hope it helps.

Comment: Paste it in the javascript console or you browser. It will continuously keep scrolling to the bottom until there is nothing left to load. *** NOTE ** It will not stop until there is nothing left to load ... meaning you won't be able to scroll up until it's done.

Comment: Thank u very much!